# onsubmit not firing my JS

Tags: javascript, ajax

what am i missing here?

```
<script>       
  function validateLogIn(login)
  {
    console.log(login);
    var username  = $("#username").val();
    var password  = $("#password").val();
    console.log(username, password, login);
    $.ajax({     
      url: 'login.php',    //checking the login in                     
     data: {username:username,password:password},
     type: "POST",     //Method by which data being transmitted
     dataType: 'json',                  
     success: function(data)          
    {
       console.log(data);
       login.submit();
    } 
      //else do an alert("please lgo in again");       
  });  
  return false;
 }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
     <form action="crud.html" method="post" name="form-login" onsubmit="return validateLogIn(this);">
     <input required placeholder="Username" type="text" name="username" id="username"/>
     <input required placeholder="Password" type="password" name="password" id="password"/>
     <label for="remember">Remember Me:</label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="yes">
     <br />
     <br />
     <input type="submit" name="login" value="login" />
 </form>
 </body>
```

have i got a spelling mistake? my console.logs doesnt show either

Comment: Have you tried it this way? `onsubmit="validateLogIn(this)"`

Comment: console.log() method take one parameter change three arguments into one big string argument check the below answer for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is working perfectly on my machine, please make sure you are including the jquery library correctly. and obviously `return false`

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>    

      function validateLogIn()
      {
        var username  = $("#username").val();
        var password  = $("#password").val();
        console.log(username, password, this);
        alert("Hello");
        $.ajax({     
          url: 'login.php',    //checking the login in                     
         data: {username:username,password:password},
         type: "POST",     //Method by which data being transmitted
         dataType: 'json',                  
         success: function(data)          
        {
           console.log(data);
        } 
          //else do an alert("please lgo in again");       
      });  
return false;
     }
     </script>
    </head>
    <body>
         <form action="crud.html" method="post" name="form-login" onsubmit="return validateLogIn();">
         <input required placeholder="Username" type="text" name="username" id="username"/>
         <input required placeholder="Password" type="password" name="password" id="password"/>
         <label for="remember">Remember Me:</label>
         <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="yes">
         <br />
         <br />
         <input type="submit" name="login" value="login" />
     </form>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: To avoid such situations i use html templates predefined in eclipse, i think might be a good choice for you as well

Answer (score 2):

In your `validateLogIn()` function, you aren't returning `false`, therefore the function will be called, but the browser will still proceed to submit the form to `crud.html` and change page.

```
function validateLogIn(login)
{
  ...
  ...
  ...
  return false;
}
```

If you want to submit to `crud.html` only after the success function fires, then you still need the above `return false`, and in your success function add:

```
success: function(data)          
{
  login.submit();
}
```

Comment: thank you i added these lines but still not executing JS, please see amendments in OP

Answer (score 0):

change your log statement to this as below, the log() method takes one argument, so if you want to print three variables append it to one string

```
console.log("username:"+username+" password:"+password+" id:"+login.id);
```